# Regular expression to Star with number and then numbers or one letter

Tags: regex

I have this regular expression

```
^[0-9]+[a-zA-Z0-9]*
```

But I need one that always stars with a number then it can be another number or a letter, but it can not be number letter number. The letter will always be the last. Like this example

```
102A OK
1A OK
2  OK
110 OK
10A1 WRONG
BV WRONG
```

The letter cannot be between two numbers.

Comment: Explain: "then another number or a letter but not a letter"

Comment: Match only. digits or digits with ending with a char a-zA-Z `^[1-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9]*[A-Za-z]|[0-9]+)$` https://regex101.com/r/nQvUl8/1 Or `^[1-9][0-9]*[A-Z]*$` https://regex101.com/r/eT5HPk/1

Comment: `^[1-9][0-9]*[0-9a-zA-Z]*[a-zA-Z]$|^[1-z][0-9]*$`   https://regex101.com/r/ACGTzM/1   But, i am not an expert in regex-thing     (hmmm, the `1-z` should obviously be `1-9`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead.

```
^(?!\d+[a-z]\d)\d.*
```

with the case-indifferent flag set.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/YOxt2W/2/)

A match of this regular expression signifies that the string does not contain a 3-character substring consisting of a digit, a letter, a digit, in that order. If the entire string is to be matched when the match is successful, add `.*` to the end of the regex.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
^             match beginning of line
(?!           begin negative lookahead
  \d+[a-z]\d  match digits-letter-digit
)             end negative lookahead
\d            match a digit
```

Note that `\d` at the end must *follow* the negative lookahead. If the regex were `^\d(?!.\d+[a-z]\d)` and the string were `1A1` the negative lookahead would fail to find digit-letter-digit in `A1` and the overall match would succeed (incorrectly).

Because the negative lookahead is pinned to the beginning of the line and consumes no characters, if it fails (match succeeds) the search for `\d` at the end of the regex begins at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You could match a char 1-9 followed by optional digits 0-9 and optional chars a-zA-Z.

If you use `[a-zA-Z0-9]` the character class will match any of the listed in any order.

If you separate the chars and the digits, the letter can not come before the digits and, as the `*` quantifier matches 0 or more times, you can also match a single digit.

```
^[1-9][0-9]*[a-zA-Z]*$
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LpCAX8/1)